# Service to service communication in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast, android-background

I am new to android development.I am going to create one android service(parent service), which it will be started on boot time.Once that service is getting started ,i will start the new service(i.e child service of parent service).I want to make communication between those two services.I mean, if i receive some response in child service i need to notify that response to parent service.Thanks in advance

```
   /** Parent service **/
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    System.out.println("Parent Service started");
    boolean result=showData();
    if(result)
    {
    Intent childservice = new Intent(this, MyChildService.class);
    this.startService(childservice);
    }
    else
    {

    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

  /** Child service **/
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("My child Service Started");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Bound Service for the second service. Read about them here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~binwiederhier/+junk/android-service-example/files/head:/src/com/

Answer (score 0):

Make parent service bind to the child service, so parent will get the binder of child;
define an interface and let parent implement it, after bind to child, register parent to child, so child can call methods of parent.